# Dynamically create array of objects from the object with the array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, javascript-objects

Currently I have the below object structure,

```
`let selectedOptions = {
  "color": {
    "id": "2",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "red",
        "label": "Red",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "value": "blue",
        "label": "Blue",
        "id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "size": {
    "id": "19",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "medium",
        "label": "Medium",
        "id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "demo": {
    "id": "19",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "neylon",
        "label": "Neylon",
        "id": 2
      }
    ]
  }
  .
  .
  .
  N
}; `
```

And want to create array of objects from the above object like as below,

```
[
 { color: "red", size: "medium", demo: "neylon" },
 { color: "blue", size: "medium", demo: "neylon" }
]
```

I have tried like below but it didn't worked
https://jsfiddle.net/6Lvb12e5/18/

```
let cArr = [];
for(key in selectedOptions) {
  selectedOptions[key].values.forEach(function(val,i) {
   cArr.push({ [key]: val.value  })
  })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What if the `size` is having more than one object, how do you create your final array from that?

Comment: @AaminKhan - For example Size contains another values as Small. Then the final array should be like,
`[
 { color: "red", size: "medium", demo: "neylon" },
 { color: "red", size: "small", demo: "neylon" },
 { color: "blue", size: "medium", demo: "neylon" },
{ color: "blue", size: "small", demo: "neylon" }
]`

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Can you paste your wrong results (contained in the `cArr`, I presume)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the wanted parts, like `color`, `size` and `demo` and build a cartesian product out of the given data.

```js
const
    cartesian = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []),
    options = { color: { id: "2", values: [{ value: "red", label: "Red", id: 1 }, { value: "blue", label: "Blue", id: 2 }] }, size: { id: "19", values: [{ value: "small", label: "Small", id: 1 }, { value: "medium", label: "Medium", id: 2 }] }, demo: { id: "19", values: [{ value: "neylon", label: "Neylon", id: 2 }] } },
    parts = Object
        .entries(options)
        .map(([k, { values }]) => [k, values.map(({ value }) => value)]),
    keys = parts.map(([key]) => key),
    result = parts
        .map(([, values]) => values)
        .reduce(cartesian)
        .map(a => Object.assign(...a.map((v, i) => ({ [keys[i]]: v }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @nina-scholz, Its working. But if the `Size ` or `demo` object have more Values, then the results is not as expected. For example, if the `Size` values have another value as 'small', then the result should be as `[ { color: "red", size: "medium", demo: "neylon" }, { color: "red", size: "small", demo: "neylon" }, { color: "blue", size: "medium", demo: "neylon" }, { color: "blue", size: "small", demo: "neylon" } ]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is this the best way to do this, and even the data is missing but as a comment, it is quite big to post but can try:

```js
let selectedOptions = {
  "color": {
    "id": "2",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "red",
        "label": "Red",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "value": "blue",
        "label": "Blue",
        "id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "size": {
    "id": "19",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "medium",
        "label": "Medium",
        "id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "demo": {
    "id": "19",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": "neylon",
        "label": "Neylon",
        "id": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}; 

let cArr = [];
var obj = {};
var glob;
for(key in selectedOptions) {
  selectedOptions[key].values.forEach(function(val,i) {
  obj[key] = val.value;
  }
)
  glob = obj;
}
cArr.push(glob);
console.log(cArr)
```